# Implement 'Maybe' in Java

Tags: java

Guava's [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class comes dangerously close to being a useful `Maybe` type in Java. All I want to do is extend it a bit:

```
class Maybe<X> extends Optional<X> {
  public Maybe<Y> map(Function<X, Y> f) {
    if (isPresent()) {
      return Maybe.of(f.apply(get()));
    }
    return Maybe.absent();
  }
}
```

Is that so hard? Apparently yes, it is. Java has no idea what the `Y` type is in the `map` function, and everything dies horribly. Is it possible to write a generic `map` in Java?

Comment: Im not familiar with the `Optional` and `Maybe` classes, but there are already generic [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java

Comment: I'm not looking for key-value-pair mappings. I'm looking for the functional apply-this-function-to-your-contents mapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`Optional.transform(Function)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#transform%28com.google.common.base.Function%29), following Guava's convention of calling all `map`-style functions "transform" (e.g. Lists.transform, Iterables.transform, etc).

Comment: Well, actually, I also want to implement join and catMaybes and so on. But the implementation of Optional.transform shows me how to implement such a thing. Thanks!

(The answer, for those wondering, is to declare the function like `public <Y> Maybe<Y> map(...) {`; that's the java syntax I was missing.)

Answer (score 1):

This is, as of JDK8, implemented as java.util.Optional, and it seems to have the mapping function that you're looking for as it integrates with Streams.
[Here is the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

I know this reply is quite late, but I'm adding it as an answer for the benefit of others searching for this.